# R Markdown Knitting to PDF Format Question

Tags: r, r-markdown

This is a two-part question, both parts are probably simple:

1. Why do my comments appear between the code and the output?  I'd rather it display as I type it.  For instance:

[image]

Gives the output:

[image]

But I would prefer the "We have 7 classes of data..." line to go above the code in the PDF.

2. Using the second picture from above, why does the gray box containing the code in have a larger border above the code than below?  I'd rather the top have the same size border as the bottom.

I'm assuming this is an easy setting to change but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to include a complete document, not just a screenshot of part of it.

Comment: Re: 1) If you want your comments to be inside the code chunk in the generated pdf, you need to put them inside the code chunk within the script. That means putting the comment after the {r} bit. Re: 2) I don't know but maybe try putting a space after the `unique()`?

Comment: An RMarkdown document is a Markdown document that can execute chunks of R (and some other languages) code. Outside of those chunks, it's just a Markdown document, in which `#### blah blah blah` means something different from within a chunk of R code